# Node memory management issues when streaming Tweets

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm playing around with node to hook into the Twitter streaming API, but am running into some memory issues.

[Github repo](https://github.com/dragongraphics/twitter-live-streaming-poll)

I've managed to get a connection setup from my app.js to the twitter streaming API.  My server then emits a message to a dashboard on every tweet to visually update the results.  This all works great, but the memory steadily goes up and up until it hits the limit.

I'm not sure if this is just the volume of tweets that is being processed, or if memory is getting trapped and not garbage collected properly (not sure if I'm overlooking something simple?) - any help or thoughts on this?

Comment: You appear to be storing all received tweets in `watchlist`, so of course it's going to just keep consuming more memory. You even made commented your concern of such above the declaration of watchlist.

Comment: I noticed that that was one issue, but even after commenting out everything apart from the t.stream(...) call, the memory still goes up, which I'm guessing would be an issue with the nTwitter module consuming the memory...